# Changing DrawableLeft image size doesn't work when app launched

Tags: android, xml

> I have used an image as `drawableLeft` of a `textview` .I have changed
>   the  `width` and `height` as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrowforlist"
        android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
        android:height="@dimen/icon_size"
        />
</layer-list >
```

> And the textview code is,

```
<TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/heading" />
```

> Here, `icon_size="20dp"`
>
> It perfectly worked in design. But when I was launching the
>   app, the image's `width` and `height` were changed to its original size.

Can anyone guide me.Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please post your dimen values ? And also check the device size.

Comment: `android:width` is not `android:layout_width` so it cannot have the value of `wrap_content` (or `match_parent`)

Comment: sorry, I just mentioned it to say it doesn't fit to the size what I assigned. It is displayed with its original size.

Comment: can you please textview code in xml? I hope you might have given textview height and width are match_parent.

Comment: No,I have used wrap_content for the height. I have edited my question now.

Comment: you have to call `TextView#setCompoundDrawables(left, null, null, null)`

Comment: You should change image size then the result will be according to you.

Comment: might be try like this 
`Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s_vit);

drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5),(int)(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));

ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

Textview btn = findViewbyId(R.id.textview);
btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);`

Comment: But, I am using that textview to display the listview item. How can I use this logic in my custom adapter? It extends BaseAdapter.

Comment: just call `TextView#setCompoundDrawables(left, null, null, null)` - no need for `ScaleDrawable`

Comment: you can keep this in the adapter class.